# Auto refresh with jquery gets echo "test" but it does not get data from mysql query.. How can i fix it?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i will try to explain this as clear as possible.. I have a auto refresh script. This script auto refresh a div. I want to call a php file in this div which has mysql in it.. When i try to call that php file only the manual echos display. It does not display anything from database.. If i check the php file i see that it works on its own.. How can i fix this? Thanks.

My script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#feeds").load("sagmenu.php");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("#feeds").load("sagmenu.php");
    }, 2000);
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>

<div id='feeds'></div>
```

My PHP:

```
<?php 
$feeddatagetsq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM feed ORDER BY id DESC");
$feeddataget = mysql_fetch_array($feeddatagetsq);

echo $feeddataget['id'];   //this does not display.. I want this to display..
echo "test"; //this displays..
?>
```

Comment: Try `var_dump($feeddataget);`

Comment: please check first that your query fetch data from database or not

Comment: Might be a good idea to set cache to false right at the top even before the first AJAX request.

Comment: If that's the only PHP code being executed: where's your connect statement?!?

Comment: the page which has the div had connection.. i thought it will be enough.. i added another connection to the php i call and it worked.. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

load() function loads only the html part of the file. So if you want datas from database just echo it

Answer (score 0):

My friend, the `$feeddataget['id']` is not a single record. It is returning more than 1 rows (Obviously only with ID column). So according to me, you cannot send this simply by echoing into PHP file.

Use this instead:

```
echo json_encode($feeddataget['id']);
```

and in JS File, use this:
`var foo = $.parseJSON(responseText);` (If you wanna implement it through JQuery)
and, `var foo = JSON.parse(responseText);` (If you want to do it without JQuery)

Now, foo is a array containing all the IDs that you've returned from PHP File.